# I need to post url with rest API call. it was working in angular 1.6 but not able to post it with Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, http

I need to post url with angular 7 to the server but getting some error as "blocked by CORS policy" while it was working in angular 1.6

Getting issue as :Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

```
return this.http.post<Driver>(url, this.emailAttributeObject, {
                    headers : new HttpHeaders({
                        'Content-type' : 'application/json'
                    })
                })
                    .pipe(
                        catchError(this.handleError('driverDetails', driverDetails))
                    );

component file:
this.myDataService.sendEmail(this.driverDetails, this.initialValue)
            .subscribe((response : Driver) => {
                    //this.driverDetails = response;
                }, error =>
                    this.toastr.error(error.message,"Problem to send Email")
            )

service file:
return this.http.post<Driver>(url, this.emailAttributeObject, {
                    headers : new HttpHeaders({
                        'Content-type' : 'application/json'
                    })
                })
                    .pipe(
                        catchError(this.handleError('driverDetails', driverDetails))
                    );
```

Comment: The CORS policy usually is managed on the server side. The response headers need to include the following `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'` and possibly `'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use proxy config to bypass this issue.You can learn more about it from here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Answer (score 0):

In development environment, you can disable web security.
For chrome, use the following:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```